# How can I make a clickable button in OpenTK?

Tags: c#, button, opentk

I'm trying to make a class for button in OpenTK.

Is there a nice way to make a button?

If it can show description when hovering above it, it would be more appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options.

1. Embed an OpenTK context inside a Windows form using `GLControl`. Downside here is that no button can be placed within the OpenTK window, but depending on your goal here this might be not be a problem.
2. Render a button yourself and test for mouse presses within that region.

Option 2 will be more work but clearly more versatile, and if you're starting out you will learn a lot.

To get the cursor location...

```
int mouseX = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X;
int mouseY = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y;
```

To check for mouse presses...

```
MouseState mouseState = OpenTK.Input.Mouse.GetState();
bool leftMouseDown = mouseState.IsButtonDown(MouseButton.Left);
bool rightMouseDown = mouseState.IsButtonDown(MouseButton.Right);
```

And to draw a quad at per pixel co-ordinates...

```
float x1 = (float)x * 2 / screenWidth - 1;
float x2 = (float)(x + buttonWidth) * 2 / screenWidth - 1;
float y1 = (float)y * 2 / screenHeight - 1;
float y2 = (float)(y + buttonHeight) * 2 / screenHeight - 1;
```

The rest is up to you my friend.